# How to get last 7 days and last 1 month revenue into the same table? Can somebody look at this query?

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT 
"Fact Order Item"."product_therapy" AS "Product_therapy"

,(select sum(total_order_value_inc_tax_uc) FROM "d2c"."fact_order"
WHERE and date_created  >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) ) as "REVENUE - T7"

,(select sum(total_order_value_inc_tax_uc) FROM "d2c"."fact_order"
WHERE and date_created  >= DATEADD(day,-30, GETDATE()) ) as "REVENUE - T30"

FROM "d2c"."fact_order"

LEFT JOIN "d2c"."fact_order_item" ON "d2c"."fact_order"."order_id" = "Fact Order Item"."order_id"

WHERE "d2c"."fact_order"."is_active" = '1'

GROUP BY "Fact Order Item"."product_therapy"
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server

Comment: I am using my sql. tag fixed

Comment: You need to either add predicates to your subqueries so they ONLY get the rows for the current product_therapy or better yet, use a case expression instead of those subqueries for conditional aggregation.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more? Thanks sean!

Comment: Well the way you have this coded you will get the same value in those two columns with subqueries on every row. I mean surely you have run your query and noticed that right?

Comment: SELECT 
"Fact Order Item"."product_therapy" AS "Product_therapy"
,sum(case when date_created  >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) then total_order_value_inc_tax_uc ELSE 0.0 END) AS "REVENUE - T7"
FROM "d2c"."fact_order"
LEFT JOIN "d2c"."fact_order_item" A  ON "d2c"."fact_order"."order_id" = A."order_id"
WHERE "d2c"."fact_order"."is_active" = '1'
GROUP BY "Fact Order Item"."product_therapy"

Comment: I did yes. same value for all the rows

Comment: Two issues with that. First it is running both of those subqueries for every row which is performance timebomb, secondly  it is wrong. You have grouping on the query so those totals should reflect the total for the group right? Either add a where predicate to those subqueries to make them correlated or as I said before use a case expression inside a SUM function.

Comment: It would really be easier if you could show me a sample query or one corrected above. Really appreciate your help btw!

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/3419/conditional-aggregation

Comment: There are thousands and thousands more examples using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Done. The SQL code is running smoothly. Thanks. You are the best!

Comment: Which way did you go?

Comment: Case statement!